# Overwriting lines in a txt file while searching for the lines

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm working on a video game with C#. I have a list of users with their coin amounts in a .txt file, and I want for their amounts to be overwritten when they save. I can't figure out how to use SteamWriter within SteamReader without a "file already being used" exception. Basically, I need to search for a username, and if it finds it, overwrite the existing line with the same username and the new amount of coins. All the coin amounts are in the "0000" format (0010, 0199, etc.), so I can use Substring and length to easily find and load the coin amounts.

Here is the code I have tried to use:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\FakeFilePath");
String line;
try
{
  line = sr.ReadLine();
  while (line != null)
  {
     if (line.Contains(users[m.GetInt(0)].username))
     {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\FakeFilePath", false))
        {
            file.WriteLine("\n" + users[m.GetInt(0)].username + " " + (users[m.GetInt(0)].rupees).ToString("D4"));
            file.Close();
        }
     }
     line = sr.ReadLine();
  }
}
finally
{
    sr.Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Thanks,
dsimathguy

Comment: The easiest way by far will be to read the entire file into memory, do your replace, then re-write the entire file back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should do this by simply rewriting the entire file, as suggested by commenter Jonesy. It's likely the text file is relatively small, probably smaller than a single disk block (normally 4K in size, but could vary depending on file system configuration), and rewriting the whole thing will be practically as fast as just overwriting a specific spot.

If you do insist on trying to overwrite just a specific spot, you need a reliable way to compute the location in the file where you want to write, and then you will need to set the position of the `StreamWriter.BaseStream` object before writing the new data. You will also need to either open the file once with read/write access, or open it once for reading to find the location, and then close it before opening it again for writing.

The easiest way to compute the location in the file is to assume a fixed-size character encoding, e.g. ASCII or UTF16. With ASCII, the offset in the file in bytes will be the same as the number of characters; with UTF16, it will be twice the number of characters.

Note that each line must have a fixed length as well; i.e. you are storing the username in a fixed-width field in the line, as well as the coin count. So the file might look something like this:

```
Username1     0001
User24        0117
SallyDoe999   0037
```

Note: the above has 20 characters per line: 14 characters for the name, 4 characters for the coin count, plus of course the two characters for the newline.

For example, let's assume you are storing the data as ASCII:

```
string fileName = "C:\\FakeFilePath";

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    String line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(users[m.GetInt(0)].username))
        {
            // Offset is the offset of the line itself, plus
            // the length of the name field (the name field doesn't
            // need to be written because it's already the right
            // value!)
            int byteOffset = (lineCount * 20) + 14;

            writer.BaseStream.Position = byteOffset;
            writer.Write(users[m.GetInt(0)].rupees.ToString("D4"));

            break;
        }

        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

As you can see, that's a lot of effort, especially if you ever have to change the file format. There's a lot of finicky "has to be just right" code there, and it of course significantly constrains your options in terms of what the file format can look like. I hope you can see the wisdom in simply writing the whole file out all over again any time it needs to be changed. :)

Comment: Brilliant! Not only do you find code that will do what I asked, but you suggested a solution that will work even better! Thanks for the help, I'll use the File.WriteAllText method instead.